# Server wasn't able to start properly. [2020-04-25T07:05:35.422Z] error (hook:bookshelf) takes too long to load (hook:bookshelf) takes too long to load

Tags: server, installation, content-management-system, strapi

Issue occuring while creating strapi project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TAQM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `config/hook.json` and increase `timeout` value to `30000`.

It will fix the issue.